# Can a normal distribution be approximated with a binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem

We know that a binomial distribution can be approximated with a normal distribution when $n * p$ is large where $n$ and $p$ are the number of bernoulli trials and $p$ is the probability of success of a bernoulli trial. So binom(n, p) can be approximated with $N(np, np(1-p))$

I am wondering if we can somehow do the reverse? i.e., given a normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, can we find parameters $n$ and $p$ and approximate the normal distribution with a binomial distribution?

Answer (score 3):

You can always just solve for $n$ and $p$ in terms of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.  Given a normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, set $p = 1 - \frac{\sigma^2}{\mu}$ and $n = \frac{\mu}{1-\sigma^2/\mu}$ (if this isn't an integer, just round it).  Then you know that the binomial distribution $\operatorname{Binom}(n,p)$ will be approximately equal to $N(np, np(1-p)) \approx N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

EDIT: Also this is only possible if $\sigma^2 < \mu$, else you would get $p<0$.

Comment: Is this a valid approach to approximating a normal distribution with discrete binomial distribution? I've never seen it done before.

Comment: Also let's say you wanted to evaluate the normal pdf at some $X=x$, and now what you've transformed it to a binomial distribution, how would you evaluate the binomial distribution at this value?

Comment: @student010101 I would say that it's just as valid as approximating a binomial by a normal.  Maybe a better statement is "Binomial and normal distributions approximate each other".  The reason we usually use a normal to approximate a binomial is because normal distributions are very easy to do calculations with, but binomial distributions (when n is large) are very hard to do calculations with.  So you could go from a normal distribution to a binomial distribution that approximates it if you wanted, but probably it would make all your calculations harder.